# Finding and classifying the singularities of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function $f(z) = ze^{-\frac{1}{z^2}}$. I am trying to find and classify the singularities.

I know the only singularity could be at $z = 0$. But from here, how do I know whether this singularity is removable, a pole, or essential?

I tried plotting the graph with a calculator, but that didn't yield much information.

Also, I believe that the only possible singularity is 0. But I may be wrong and there could be more.

Comment: Hint: try looking at the Laurent series expansion for $f$

Answer (score 0):

For this particular function, the most effective way is to consider its Laurent series. Supposing you are familiar with the Taylor expansion of $e^w$, you substitute $w = -\frac{1}{z^2}$ and get

$$f(z) = z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\tfrac{1}{z^2})^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(-1)^n}{n!z^{2n-1} },$$

which contains infinitely many negative powers of $z$. Hence, the singularity is essential.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(z)=z\mathrm{e}^{-1/z^2}
$$
has essential singularity at $z=0$.

An isolated singularity is essential if and only if the Laurent development around it has infinite principal part.

In this case, the Laurent development is
$$
z\mathrm{e}^{-1/z^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}z^{-(2n-1)},
$$
and clearly possesses infinitely many negative terms.

Comment: How do we know that the function does not have any other singularities? My reasoning is that $z$ is analytic everywhere and $e^{-\frac{1}{z^2}}$ is analytic everywhere except 0, and hence their product which is $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere except 0. And hence there can be no other singularities.

Comment: Because, the Laurent expansions around poles and removable singularities do not possess infinite many negative terms.